# Cortex-M0+ (STM32G0B1RETx) sometimes not returnig from function and executing next instructions

Tags: c, stm32, freertos, cortex-m

I've a strange problem with Cortex-M0+ (STM32G0B1RETx) when running FreeRTOS (10.3.1 heap3) and gui using lvgl (v8.3), toolchain GNU Tools for STM32 9-2020-q2-update, configuration generated from STM32CubeIDE. It occurs in random places, mostly related to size of code - changes moves it in difference places. Currently problem occurs in code responsible for handling events from buttons:

```
static void leftEventHandler(lv_event_t *e) {
    lv_event_code_t code = lv_event_get_code(e);
    uint8_t index = (uint8_t)e->user_data;
    if (code == LV_EVENT_CLICKED) {
        onLeftPressed(index);
    }
}
```

By randomly pressing buttons or even entering view that using it sometimes function will not return and execute next code from memory which happens to be:

```
static void fragmentAttach(lv_fragment_t *self) {
    Presenter_onStart();
}
```

Disassembly:

```
          leftEventHandler:
08040700:   push    {r4, lr}
08040702:   movs    r4, r0
08040704:   bl      0x800f1f0 <lv_event_get_code>
168           if (code == LV_EVENT_CLICKED) {
08040708:   cmp     r0, #7
0804070a:   bne.n   0x8040714 <leftEventHandler+20>
169               Presenter_onLeftPressed(index);
0804070c:   ldr     r0, [r4, #12]
0804070e:   uxtb    r0, r0
08040710:   bl      0x8047080 <Presenter_onLeftPressed>
08040714:   pop     {r4, pc}
120           Presenter_onStart();
          fragmentAttach:
08040716:   push    {r4, lr}
08040718:   bl      0x8046fbc <Presenter_onStart>
0804071c:   pop     {r4, pc}
0804071e:   movs    r0, r0
```

It looks like "pop     {r4, pc}" doesn't update pc sometimes, r4 is correctly restored. "push    {r4, lr}" does correctly place registers on stack and those values are unchanged when "pop" is called. "Presenter_onLeftPressed" is not called, usually "code != LV_EVENT_CLICKED" when problem occurs.

Breakpoint at "fragmentAttach" 08040716:

[registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAYpi.png)
[memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIcZx.png)

Increased stack size for threads doesn't fix the problem. Disable all threads, living only idle and timer tasks is causing hardfault at scheduler task.

Comment: r4 having the same value doesn't really mean it was popped, it is callee saved and only being pushed to keep the stack aligned.  I think the problem may be in Presenter_onStart.

Comment: it is not possible and you do not correctly interpret the result. Maybe you overflow the stack or have UB resulting in such behavior. **It is your code** issue not uC or toolchain problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of fighting with this issue I found the fix. Disabling "Prefetch Buffer" in STM32CubeMX fixed problem :)

Comment: Does your code/image span multiple flash banks? The errata mentions *"Prefetch failure when branching across flash memory banks"*, which can be avoided by disabling the prefetch buffer. Maybe this is what happens in your case.